# Excel: How to check values in mutiple rows which mark values per day and highlight row with the earliest entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a database wich shows value assigned to each customer in each week of the year. What I want is to have highlighted (i.e. marked with X, at the very end of my report) the earliest week on which any value is present for a Customer with the same Attribute, so that I can eliminate the rest of the rows for each Customer/Attribute combination. Example:

### current

[image: What I have]

### desired

[image: What I want]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Can you please clarify what you are attempting, what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: Is it possible to sort on column A?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C$2:$G$10)/(INDEX((A2=$A$2:$A$10)*(B2=$B$2:$B$10)*($C$2:$G$10),)>0),1)=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C2:$G2)/(ISNUMBER($C2:$G2)),1)
```

[image]

As you can see I left it returning TRUE/FALSE.  If you want the `X` then use this:

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C$2:$G$10)/(INDEX((A2=$A$2:$A$10)*(B2=$B$2:$B$10)*($C$2:$G$10),)>0),1)=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C2:$G2)/(ISNUMBER($C2:$G2)),1),"X","")
```

It will return `X` or a blank cell.

The AGGREGATE() function was introduced in excel 2010.

Note:

It will return TRUE to all that are tied for the earliest.